# Is there a technical term for the two halves of an email address?

Tags: terminology, neologisms

Is there a technical name for the two halves of an email address? I mean the parts before and after the @ sign.

As a kind of example of what I mean, for [UK postcodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom), I believe the two halves are called the *inward* and *outward*, not by the general population, but by people who work with postcode data.

Comment: For UK postcodes the terms are *inward* and *outward*, based on the idea that the first half indicted the sorting office where post would go in from other sorting offices,  before going out to individuals.

Comment: @Henry, you're right, i couldn't remember it exactly and couldn't find a reference. i'll edit

Comment: Rightly belongs on the SO site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, although it is not commonly mentioned, even in Computer Science:

> The part before the @ sign is the **local-part** of the address, often the username of the recipient (jsmith), and the part after the @ sign is a **domain name** to which the email message will be sent (example.org).

from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address).

Comment: Might as well link to the canonical document: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696#section-3 which says *"Contemporary email addresses consist of a "local part" separated from a "domain part" (a fully-qualified domain name) by an at-sign ("@")."*

Comment: Yup, note that this notation is inspired from unix login notation, for example if I want to log in as user dvador to google.com through ssh, I will type: ssh dvador@google.com

Comment: SMTP/UUCP email predates SSH by quite a long time. SSH here is borrowing convention from those.